# Read domain from IBM Worklight Adapter

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

I am building a HTTP Adapter in Worklight. Normal communication between the server and application works great, but I need to retrieve an image from the server. The image can be downloaded using a URL which contains the image ID, but I don't know how I can return the whole URL and not only the path. A simple version of my function is:

```
function getFile(id) {
    if (typeof id == 'undefined') return {isSuccesful : false};

    return {isSuccesful : true, url : '/api/media/get/' + id.toString()};
}
```

But my path returns only:

```
'/api/media/get/1'
```

The URL I need is:

```
'http://www.example.com/api/media/get/1'
```

How can I retrieve the domain from the .xml file?

Comment: Are you asking you want to return the URL of the WorklightServer ?

Comment: I want to retrieve the URL the Worklight Server communicates with. At the moment this is a Tomcat server which runs local on my computer, but in the future it will be another URL. The reason I need to know this, is because this adapter will be used in multiple occasions and I don't want to change to much in the settings (one file if possible).

Comment: Saying you want the adapter URL which you are trying to access right :)

Comment: No, I think I can't explain it right. I am trying to get the domain which is set in de adapter .xml file. Which is my local tomcat server at the moment, but will be hosted on another server when going into production. It is the domain in the .xml file inside the connectivity -> connectionPolicy -> domain node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting MobileFirst Platform (Worklight) 6.3, there is client-side API to get/get the Server URL the application will attempt connecting to/send requests to.

See the following blog post which expends and demonstrates using WL.App.getServerURL/getServerURL: [Changing the Server URL during runtime](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/02/02/changing-server-url-runtime/)

If you are referring to the URL that you have set in the Adapter XML file (meaning the address the adapter request will be sent to from the server), then you cannot retrieve this address during runtime.

If you are using MobileFirst Platform 7.0, then you can now use multiple URLs in the same adapter: [Changing the adapter host at runtime](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/03/20/changing-adapter-host-runtime/)

Comment: I am referring to the URL that I have set in the adapter .xml file. So not the Worklight / MobileFirst server, but the server where the Worklight server communicates with and which is set in the .xml file as the domain. Too bad it isn't accessible during runtime.

Comment: If you'll use MFPF 7.0 then you'll be at a better position to handle that.

Comment: I have read the last URL for MobileFirst Platform 7.0. I don't need to use multiple hosts, but just want to return the host I am currently using. Although 7.0 could also solve this. I'll try to convince the group to update to a newer version!